# db = DBH.getWritableDatabase(); == null; What to do?

Tags: java, sqlite

I am new to android and ran into a problem: I decided to make a method in a separate class to read data from the database. When I use the getWritableDatabase () method; an error comes up:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath (java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

As I understand it, db is Null, but what happens and how to solve it I don’t know.

> public void readDB(){

```
DBH = new DBHelper(this);
        db = DBH.getWritableDatabase();
        c = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);
```

> DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    Context mContext;
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ActionsDB";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ActionTable";


    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String KEY_SWITCH = "switch";
    public static final String KEY_BALANCE = "balance";
    public static final String KEY_BALANCEND = "balancend";
    public static final String KEY_TARGET = "target";
    public static final String KEY_CURRENCY = "currency";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE ="create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT not null, "
            + KEY_TYPE + " INTEGER, "
            + KEY_SWITCH + " INTEGER, "
            + KEY_BALANCE + " REAL, "
            + KEY_BALANCEND + " REAL, "
            + KEY_TARGET +"  REAL, "
            + KEY_CURRENCY + " TEXT);";



    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NAME");
        onCreate(db);


    }

}
```

What do I need to do so that there is no error?

Comment: What is `this` you're passing in as `Context`?

Comment: The class in which the readDB extends AppCompactActivity method is located, do you want to know this? If not, please tell me what you mean, I'm new and still poorly versed in this.

Comment: How are you instantiating that activity? (You shouldn't do it yourself.)

Comment: hmm... No way... It turns out the context is null and therefore the method does not work. AppCompatActivivty is completely unnecessary here. But if you remove this, then an error occurs. What should be done?

Comment: If the readDB()'s code is exactly as you posted then context can't be null. So is this your actual code?

Comment: Yes. I don’t know why it gives me such an error.

Comment: What method is used in Fragment matters?